# How to override styles for children of an element with a specific class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, dom

There are many elements with the same class in their children, but different classes for the elements themselves:

```js
<div class='first'>
  <p class='item'><p>
  <p class='item'><p>
</div>
<div class='second'>
  <p class='item'><p>
  <p class='item'><p>
<div>
...
```

How to override styles only for the children of an element with the 'first' class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5041526/402037

Comment: Are you looking to only apply pseudo elements on div wich are not `.a .subA` (css) or remove it when an event is triggered (js) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the display property to `none`.

Use a descendant combinator to select only the elements you want to target.

```
.a .subA::after {
    display: none;
}
```

Make sure your selector is [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) enough. (You didn't supply a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can't tell how specific we need to be).

Answer (score -1):

Exactly as you said:

```
div.a .subA::after{
  display: none;
}
```